# How to auto add "missing whitespace" in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, whitespace, lint, tslint

I have some `tslint` errors for "missing whitespace" in React project.

Is there a way I can auto fix (auto add) them without disabling rule?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can auto fix (auto add) them without disabling rule?

Add prettier to your project and it will format the code for you.

## More

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-prettier

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code under settings, search for format, and click `typescript`, you will see a few `whitespace` options. Choose your prefered setting(s). Please see screenshot below.

[image]